# Camel stops responsing after getting TimeOut for an exchange

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm routing `ActiveMQ` messages by `Camel` between two other components.
when Camel throws `ExchangeTimedOutException`, it's not responding to other request from the corresponding client. I should restart camel when this happens!
Why? and how to fix this to continue working after that.

my route:

```
// ----<Exception Handler>----
onException(Exception.class).to("activemqException:queue:Q.SException");

// ----<the Route>----
from("activemq:queue:Q.S")
.threads(2, 20)
.inOut("activemq2:queue:Q.DB?requestTimeout=60s");
```

and the stackTrace for TimeOut:

```
2014-07-08 11:23:40.098 [WARN ] TemporaryQueueReplyManager(Camel (camel-1) thread #38 - JmsReplyManagerTimeoutChecker[Q.DB]):126 - Timeout occurred after 60000 millis waiting for reply message with correlationID [ce4a53fd7821480fbe482717728063f2]. Setting ExchangeTimedOutException on (MessageId: queue_Q.S_ID_S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1_26_1_2_1 on ExchangeId: ID-localhost-localdomain-58884-1404800138167-0-80) and continue routing.
2014-07-08 11:23:40.105 [ERROR] DefaultErrorHandler(Camel (camel-1) thread #38 - JmsReplyManagerTimeoutChecker[Q.DB]):161 - Failed delivery for (MessageId: queue_Q.S_ID_S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1_26_1_2_1 on ExchangeId: ID-localhost-localdomain-58884-1404800138167-0-80). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 60000 millis due reply message with correlationID: ce4a53fd7821480fbe482717728063f2 not received. Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1:26:1:2:1]]. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[activemqException://queue:Q.SException])]]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                              Elapsed (ms)
[route7            ] [route7            ] [activemq://queue:Q.S                                               ] [     60205]
[route7            ] [threads7          ] [threads                                                            ] [     60205]
[null              ] [to2               ] [log:ir.sy.S.SFileLogger?level=INFO&showAll=true                    ] [         1]
[null              ] [to3               ] [log:ir.sy.S.SConsoleLogger?level=INFO&showAll=true                 ] [         0]
[route7            ] [to10              ] [activemq2:queue:Q.DB?requestTimeout=60s                            ] [     60205]
[null              ] [to2               ] [log:ir.sy.S.SFileLogger?level=INFO&showAll=true                    ] [         1]
[null              ] [to3               ] [log:ir.sy.S.SConsoleLogger?level=INFO&showAll=true                 ] [         0]
[null              ] [to1               ] [activemqException:queue:Q.SException                               ] [         5]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
    Id                  ID-localhost-localdomain-58884-1404800138167-0-80
    ExchangePattern     InOut
    Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID:S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1:26:1:2:1, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, JMSCorrelationID=ce4a53fd7821480fbe482717728063f2, JMSDeliveryMode=2, JMSDestination=queue://Q.S, JMSExpiration=0, JMSMessageID=ID:S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1:26:1:2:1, JMSPriority=4, JMSRedelivered=false, JMSReplyTo=queue://Q.j, JMSTimestamp=1404802587776, JMSType=null, JMSXGroupID=null, JMSXUserID=null, Title=TestTrades}
    BodyType            java.util.HashMap
    Body                {...}
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 60000 millis due reply message with correlationID: ce4a53fd7821480fbe482717728063f2 not received. Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1:26:1:2:1]]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:133) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:61) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap.onEviction(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:53) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap.onEviction(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:30) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.purge(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:212) [camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.run(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:162) [camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [?:1.7.0_25]
2014-07-08 11:24:01.002 [WARN ] TemporaryQueueReplyManager(Camel (camel-1) thread #42 - JmsReplyManagerTimeoutChecker[Q.SException]):126 - Timeout occurred after 20000 millis waiting for reply message with correlationID [ce4a53fd7821480fbe482717728063f2]. Setting ExchangeTimedOutException on (MessageId: queue_Q.S_ID_S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1_26_1_2_1 on ExchangeId: ID-localhost-localdomain-58884-1404800138167-0-80) and continue routing.
2014-07-08 11:24:01.003 [ERROR] FatalFallbackErrorHandler(Camel (camel-1) thread #42 - JmsReplyManagerTimeoutChecker[Q.SException]):53 - Exception occurred while trying to handle previously thrown exception on exchangeId: ID-localhost-localdomain-58884-1404800138167-0-80 using: [Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[activemqException://queue:Q.SException])]]. The previous and the new exception will be logged in the following.
2014-07-08 11:24:01.004 [ERROR] FatalFallbackErrorHandler(Camel (camel-1) thread #42 - JmsReplyManagerTimeoutChecker[Q.SException]):54 - \--> Previous exception on exchangeId: ID-localhost-localdomain-58884-1404800138167-0-80
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 60000 millis due reply message with correlationID: ce4a53fd7821480fbe482717728063f2 not received. Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1:26:1:2:1]]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:133) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:61) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap.onEviction(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:53) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap.onEviction(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:30) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.purge(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:212) [camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.run(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:162) [camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [?:1.7.0_25]
2014-07-08 11:24:01.005 [ERROR] FatalFallbackErrorHandler(Camel (camel-1) thread #42 - JmsReplyManagerTimeoutChecker[Q.SException]):55 - \--> New exception on exchangeId: ID-localhost-localdomain-58884-1404800138167-0-80
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: ce4a53fd7821480fbe482717728063f2 not received. Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1:26:1:2:1]]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:133) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:61) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap.onEviction(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:53) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap.onEviction(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:30) [camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.purge(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:212) [camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.run(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:162) [camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [?:1.7.0_25]
2014-07-08 11:24:01.007 [WARN ] EndpointMessageListener(Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - JmsConsumer[Q.S]):136 - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: ce4a53fd7821480fbe482717728063f2 not received. Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1:26:1:2:1]]]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: ce4a53fd7821480fbe482717728063f2 not received. Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1:26:1:2:1]]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1363) ~[camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback.done(EndpointMessageListener.java:186) ~[camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:107) ~[camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562) ~[spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500) [spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468) [spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325) [spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263) [spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1096) [spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1088) [spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:985) [spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [?:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: ce4a53fd7821480fbe482717728063f2 not received. Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:S-Win2008R2-1732-635404151223100728-1:26:1:2:1]]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:133) ~[camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:61) ~[camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap.onEviction(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:53) ~[camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap.onEviction(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:30) ~[camel-jms-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.purge(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:212) ~[camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.run(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:162) ~[camel-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: can you try adding `.handled(true)` after `onException(Exception.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is the same as your question from May ([Apache Camel: Reply received for unknown correlationID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168278/apache-camel-reply-received-for-unknown-correlationid)), and my answer there applies here as well: when you do InOut messaging with multiple parallel producers, you need to do something to separate the responses so that each one goes back to the producer for which it is intended.

`threads(2,20)` is never going to work with `InOut`, because each route needs some means of differentiating its responses from the others.